# Fill form using FormData object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, form-data

I'm making website when user can save filled form as filter with a name like: "My filter".

He should be able to choose this filter later, click "Load" and all fields in the form should be filled like he had it last time.

To do this I'm creating FormData object with entire form, sending it using AJAX to a server and saving it in a database. Everything good for now.

When user clicks to load previously saved filter, I'm pulling it from database and have the same saved FormData object.

Is there any way to do it inversely? Now I'd like to fill entire form using FormData object. Can I do it in a simple way without using my own written iteration?

Comment: _"Can I do it in a simple way without using my own written iteration?"_ - no, there is not built-in way to do that, that's just way too rare of a use case. _"I'm pulling it from database and have the same saved FormData object"_ - an _actual_ FormData object? How would you even achieve what, what kind of serialization and re-initialization are you using for that?

Comment: You can use local storage or cookies to store this data at client side. So when ever you reload first you have to  check against local storage if no data found then you can request from database and accordingly you can show your data.